# How to zip multiple project folders in a solution using MSBuild tasks

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild-task

I want my project's build task to dynamically zip contents of each sub folder under the directory "Projects" in my solution to a separate zip file.

My project directory looks like follows

```
sources\
common\
Projects\
 Project1\
   file1.xml
   file2.xml
  Project2\
   Folder1\
     file1.xml
   Folder2\
      file2.xml
  Project3\
      file1.xml
```

This is the build task file in .proj file

```
 <Target Name="Zip">
    <CreateItem Include="Projects\**\*.*">
      <Output ItemName="ZipFiles" TaskParameter="Include" />
    </CreateItem>
    <Zip ZipFileName="$(ReleaseDir)\zip\Projects.zip" WorkingDirectory="$(ReleaseDir)" Files="@(ZipFiles)" />
  </Target>
  <Target Name="AfterBuild">
    <CallTarget Targets="Zip" />
  </Target>
```

This is zipping up the entire Projects folder into a single zip file but not how I want ie, Project1.zip, Project2.zip, Project3.zip etc.

How can I change this to produce one zip file for each folder under "Projects"?